# Income code 42 from 1042-S

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Trying to file income taxes and the code in box 1 on my 1042-S is 42 (earnings as an artist...) do you recommend entering this amount as “other income” or will it be as if I’m “self-employed” ??

I’m a US citizen, I made money from a Canadian company and they gave me this form for my filing, the 1042-S.

Is there a minimum income that doesn’t require you to file with this form?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to file in the US? Not all recipients of 1042-S have to file. Also, what work did you do - independent contractor work?

Comment: Did they know you're a US citizen? 1042-S (and the underlying 1042) should not be used for payments to US citizens or (other) US tax residents. (When US tax law, regulations, publications and forms says 'foreign' they mean 'foreign' from the perspective of the US, not of any other country.) If you perform or create art with the intent and realistic expectation of making a profit then yes it should be treated as self-employment.